# Rails 3-dependent collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

---

Hello people

I'm developing a rails 3.0.9 app with jquery and I need to perform this issue. If I select a value from a collection select (Region), another collection select (cities) should populate based on the selected value from the first one.

I was following this example http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/ but in the example they are using "semantic_form_for" and I'm just using "form_for" so, when I load the form and I choose a region, the other select box is populated and i can choose the city, at this point everything works perfect... the problem is... I can't save the form.

When I press the submit button, nothing happens (no submiting, no error messages, nothing at all), the page gets stuck.

Does anyone know how to work with dependent select boxes in rails??

Hope you can help me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think simple form really has anything to do with it.  Simpleform just provides some helpers for generating html...doesn't really help much with ajax.

What's probably happening is you have a javascript error on your page.  Open up firebug in  firefox and go to the console tab to see if there is an error.    Also your form html might be messed up, you might want to provide the source for it here so we can help.